# The rate limiting doesn't work with redis in JMeter

Tags: spring, redis, gateway, rate-limiting, gate

I don't know, is redis not working with my configuration in application.yml? Or there is another problem?
///////////////
I limit 20 requests that can pass, and in JMeter I launched 50 requests, all 50 requests are passed.